# Problem with two dynamically updated vertical lines on two charts in Chart.js

Tags: python, django, chart.js

I have a problem with updating the position of vertical lines simultaneously on plots using Chart.js. What I want to do is to draw vertical line in a specific x postion when mouse pointer is on another graph. The problem is that with the current code, after moving mouse pointer over one plot in the second I have plotted line but the plot doesn't refresh, thus after moving again pointer there are a bunch of other lines.

I was trying including `update()` option before drawing vertical lines which actually solves the problem but the whole chart is refreshed and it's very slow.
Thx for the help!

[image]

```
    Chart.defaults.LineWithLine = Chart.defaults.scatter

    Chart.controllers.LineWithLine = Chart.controllers.scatter.extend({
       draw: function(ease) {
          Chart.controllers.scatter.prototype.draw.call(this, ease);

          if (this.chart.tooltip._active && this.chart.tooltip._active.length) {
             var activePoint = this.chart.tooltip._active[0],
                 ctx = this.chart.ctx,
                 x = activePoint.tooltipPosition().x,
                 topY = this.chart.scales['y-axis-1'].top,
                 bottomY = this.chart.scales['y-axis-1'].bottom;      

             // draw line
             ctx.save();
             ctx.beginPath();
             ctx.moveTo(x, topY);
             ctx.lineTo(x, bottomY);
             ctx.lineWidth = 1.5;
             ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
             ctx.stroke();
             ctx.restore();

             // get x value 
             var xValue = map(x, this.chart.chartArea.left, this.chart.chartArea.right, chainage_min, chainage_max);

             if (this.chart == graph2) {
               try {
                // graph1.update()    // drastically slows down 
               } finally {
                //
               }
               var activePoint = graph2.tooltip._active[0],
                   ctx2 = graph1.ctx,
                   x = graph1.scales['x-axis-1'].getPixelForValue(xValue)
                   topY = graph1.scales['y-axis-1'].top,
                   bottomY = graph1.scales['y-axis-1'].bottom;

               // draw line
               ctx2.save();
               ctx2.beginPath();
               ctx2.moveTo(x, topY);
               ctx2.lineTo(x, bottomY);
               ctx2.lineWidth = 2.0;
               ctx2.strokeStyle = 'black';
               ctx2.stroke();
               ctx2.restore();

             } else if (this.chart == graph1) {
               try {
                //graph2.update()   // drastically slows down 
               } finally {
                //
               }
               var activePoint = graph1.tooltip._active[0],
                   ctx2 = graph2.ctx,
                   x = graph2.scales['x-axis-1'].getPixelForValue(xValue)
                   topY = graph2.scales['y-axis-1'].top,
                   bottomY = graph2.scales['y-axis-1'].bottom;

               // draw line
               ctx2.save();
               ctx2.beginPath();
               ctx2.moveTo(x, topY);
               ctx2.lineTo(x, bottomY);
               ctx2.lineWidth = 2.0;
               ctx2.strokeStyle = 'black';
               ctx2.stroke();
               ctx2.restore();
             }
          }
       }
})

function map(value, start1, stop1, start2, stop2) {
        return start2 + (stop2 - start2) * ((value - start1) / (stop1 - start1))
    }
```

Comment: Try `graph2.update(0)` to update the chart without animation, as per [the manual](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/updates.html#preventing-animations).

Comment: @timclutton Thx for the hint but my charts are already without animations. I have a lot of data plotted so refreshing whole plot is very slow. I was thinking if there is a way just to delete previously drawn line?

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not how the `canvas` element works. It's a stateless 2D render. It's normally wiped clean and everything's redrawn, but this usually happens very quickly so as to create the illusion of animation.

Comment: @timclutton Ok, but how is possible that when I have vertical line following mouse pointer just in one plot everything works really smooth while having at the same time vertical line in the second plot leads to serious slowdown?
Is there some way ti improve it?